# Getting the clicked value from an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I go about getting the value/Reason of the selected item? I want to store this value in a variable and throw it in sessionStorage for the next page. I suppose there is a much better way to do all this, but I have no idea how, if there is let me know please!

I am quite new to JS and would appreciate some general direction as to how one would approach this.  Thank you.

```js
$(".reasons_items").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("reasons_items_click");
});
```

```css
ul.reasons_menu li.reasons_items {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #596467;
  border-right: 1px solid #596467;
  border-left: 1px solid #596467;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #596467;
  height: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0192C9;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.reasons_menu li.reasons_items:hover,
ul.reasons_menu.reasons_items.reasons_items_click {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="reasons_menu">
  <li class="reasons_top_item">
    <h2>Why</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="reasons_items">
    <p>Reason 1</p><i class="fa fa-database fa-3x"></i></li>
  <li class="reasons_items">
    <p>Reason 2</p><i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x"></i></li>
  <li class="reasons_items">
    <p>Reason 3</p><i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i></li>
  <li class="reasons_items">
    <p>Reason 4</p><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-3x"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The value? Do you mean the `text()`?

Comment: `$(this).find("p").text();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here is a different approach to solve your problem.
Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/4mqbcgfx/

```
$(".reasons_items").click(function () {
    $('.reasons_items').removeClass("reasons_items_click");
    $(this).addClass("reasons_items_click");
    $('.reasons_top_item h2').text($('.reasons_items_click p').text())
});
```

The expected value is reflecting on first **li** having class **reasons_top_item**.

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much. Can you show me how I can put it in a session storage as well and so that is only 1 item in the session storage? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Veen, here is new fiddle link with local storage:
https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/4mqbcgfx/1/

Comment: Thank you! 1 more question, do you know how i can get the <i> element with its class and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery function like following:

```
$(".reasons_items").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("reasons_items_click");
    var clicked_text = $(this).find("p").text();
    // clicked_text variable will have the value of clicked <li>
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".reasons_items").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("reasons_items_click");
    console.log($(this).find("p").text());
});
```

This will print you text inside the li

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `$(this).find("p").text();` inside the `click` function. You can either assign it to a global variable and pass it to storage later, or set it there itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) to get the child `p` element's text and [sessionStorage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to set it for next page like,

```
$(".reasons_items").click(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('reason', //seeting key for sessionstorage
          $(this).toggleClass("reasons_items_click") // toggle class
                 .find("p") // get p element
                 .text() // get text
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just take text from `p`, as others suggest. But you are making an element that reassembles `option` element, and so I suggest the same approach.
Use `data-value` to get the value of your reasons/options like so:

`<li class="reasons_items" data-value="Reason1"><p>Reason 1</p><i class="fa fa-database fa-3x"></i></li>`

Comment: document.getElementById("reasons_items").value doesnt seem to spit out the data value?

Comment: Of course, that's different things, you need to use `dataset` property. look more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)